# How to add/test inexisting element in a XLS template?

Tags: html, xml, sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007

## Context

This is for a **Custom Query Web Part** (CQWP) in **SharePoint 2007**. I am extracting a list of event from a calendar and I want to display a list of current system State for all system, even if they have no current event.

*The list is ordered by system name.*

## XML received

Suppose you have **either** XML :

```
<events>
    <event>
        <system>A</system>
        <state>1</state>
    </event>
    <event>
        <system>B</system>
        <state>2</state>
    </event>
    <event>
        <system>C</system>
        <state>3</state>
    </event>
</events>
```

**OR**

```
<events>
    <event>
        <system>A</system>
        <state>1</state>
    </event>

    <event>
        <system>C</system>
        <state>2</state>
    </event>
</events>
```

**Note** : 3 static *system* (A,B or C). They can have no current event (I didn't put start/end date as it was unneeded for the question.)

## Data output wanted

I want my XSL output to be like :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>System</th>
        <th>State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

That is, I want to have output for all 3 systems, **even if they don't have a current event** (hence, not in the XML (Default state is 1)). Oh and yeah, 1 system could have 2+ current event. ( `<td>A</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>A</td><td>2</td>`). A **perfect** answer would concatenate same system event and only display the highest state, but I can do without.

## Current XSL

Here's the current template I have :

```
<xsl:template name="system" match="Row[@Style='system']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
        <table><tr><th>System</th>
        <th>State</th></tr>
    </xsl:if>
    <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@System"/></td>
             <td><xsl:value-of select="@State"/></td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:if test="count(following-sibling::*)=0">
        </table>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

## What I thought

I though I could use a variable (or 3?) to contain my list of (static) system

```
<xsl:variable name="Systems">A,B,C</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:variable name="System1">A</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:variable name="System2">B</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:variable name="System3">C</xsl:variable>
```

Then, in XSL, check if `<xsl:value-of select="@System"/>` ever equals this/those variable value.

## Questions

Is it doable?

Would you suggest me to proceed otherwise, if so, how?

How can I compare my variable(s) to `<xsl:value-of select="@System"/>`?

**Bonus**: How can I concatenate same system event and only display the highest state?

Comment: Your template (as the approach you are using) seems totally wrong, given the input you show. Did you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for both answerer, your example helped me understand XSL. However, since it was for SharePoint, I became aware that I'd have to play within the framework...

The case *no current event* is handled in the *mainStyle.xsl* and only display default html.

Items are handled in *itemStyle.xsl*, one by one. Most of my code was placed there.

First, I created a bunch of variables:

```
    <xsl:variable name="testACCP">
            <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="count(../Row[@Systeme='A'])>0">1</xsl:when>
            [...]
    </xsl:variable>
```

I then build up my solution, starting with a header when I was at my first node

```
     <xsl:if test="count(preceding-sibling::*)=0">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
            &lt;table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" &gt;
            [...]
```

If a System had no event, I'd know it with my variable, and display accordingly

```
<xsl:if test="$testA=0">
            <tr id="linkitem" class="item" style="background:#f0fff3">
                    <td>A</td><td>OK</td>
                    [...]
```

As for the display of the max value only, this was abandoned. There's some value to know that you have 2 current events impacting a system in the end.

This solution work, but it is sorta dumb, creating lots of variables per items to do test on a group... To optimize, a highly modified *mainstyle.xsl* or a full blown WebPart would be required.

Answer (score 1):

It's doable. If you only have 3 sites, it is easier to copy and paste to check A, B and C individually. If you want a more flexible solution, I would use the node-set() extension function but it may not be in your parser. (and there seems to be a better way in XSLT 2.0 which I do not know of.)

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>

<xsl:variable name="system">
    <system>A</system>
    <system>B</system>
    <system>C</system>  
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($system)/system">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
        <td>
            <xsl:for-each select="$root/events/event[system=current()]">
                <xsl:sort select="date" order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="state"/>
                    </xsl:if>

            </xsl:for-each>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</xsl:template>
```

I don't have a parser at hand to make sure the extension function works but hopefully it will run.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a shorter solution, probably. I couldnt figure out anyway. This is my XSLT 2.0 suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="default">
        <event>
            <system>A</system>
            <state>1</state>
        </event>
        <event>
            <system>B</system>
            <state>1</state>
        </event>
        <event>
            <system>C</system>
            <state>1</state>
        </event>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="events">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>System</th>
                <th>State</th>
            </tr>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="event[system='A']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="event[system='A'][1]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$default/event[system='A']"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="event[system='B']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="event[system='B'][1]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$default/event[system='B']"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="event[system='C']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="event[system='C'][1]"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$default/event[system='C']"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </table>        
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="event">
        <xsl:variable name="maxval" select="max(
            ../event[system=current()/system]/state)"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="system"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$maxval"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```